# How to map array?

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

i have json array object like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uniqID_Customer] => Cust-9a8a34e1
            [nama_customer] => abc
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id_customers] => Cust-9a8a34e1
                            [address] => new york
                        )
                )
        )
```

how to make single array from multidimensional array

can be able like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uniqID_Customer] => Cust-9a8a34e1
            [nama_customer] => abc
            [address] => new york
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what does codeigniter have to do with Laravel?

Comment: i'm new in laravel before using codeigniter

Comment: This can be achieved through a relatively simple loop. Have you tried writing anything? If you have, please share your effort and explain where and how it failed to do what you need.

Comment: i just use this json_decode(json_encode( eloCust::with('eloAdr','eloCustImg')->where('uniqID_Customer',$id)->get()->->toArray()),false);

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$jsonArray[0]->address = $jsonArray[0]->address[0]->address;
```